# jQueryUI IE8 Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am facing an issue I am using jquery.ui.richmedia.js.

"Object doesn't support this property or method" this error is occuring with

"toremoveTabs[i].hide()" just this line of code. I believe its something to do with hide() method as "toremoveTabs[i]" works fine at other places in the code. The code is working fine Mozilla & Chrome.

```
       resetTabs:function () {
        // remove unavailable tabs.
        var toremoveTabs = [];
        var toremoveTabNames = [];
        this._forEachTab(function (tab, i, self) {
            if (self._tabs) {
                tab = $(tab);
                var tabName = self._getTabName(tab.attr('content_id')).toLowerCase();
                if (!(tabName in self._tabs)) {
                    toremoveTabs[i] = tab;
                    toremoveTabNames[i] = tabName;
                }
            }
        });
        this._appendTabs = null;
        this._appendTabs = {};
        for (var i in toremoveTabs) {
            this._appendTabs[i] = [toremoveTabNames[i], toremoveTabs[i]];
            toremoveTabs[i].hide();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround/solution?

Answer (score 6):

I would guess that `toremoveTabs[i]` isn't a jQuery object, and is instead a regular DOM node, and as a result has no `.hide()` function available. Wrap it in a call to the `jQuery` function to create a jQuery object, giving you access to that function:

```
jQuery(toremoveTabs[i]).hide();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Anthony but if toremoveTabs[i] isn't a jQuery object how are mozilla & chrome reading it?

Comment: @ShivangSarawagi In my experience this kind of error is caused by somebody calling a jQuery function on something that isn't a jQuery object, and given the limited contextual information regarding your code I suspect the same is true in this case. I can't say why it would only not work in IE, yet work in FF or Chrome (assuming that it actually does), but I'd suggest trying this and seeing if it fixes the problem.